# Temporary failure in name resolution Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, ip, ping

I have a brand new machine and get this error after every reboot.

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search fios-router.home
```

I fixed it this morning by doing this.

```
ifconfig // get all devices
ip addr flush dev enp53s0
ip addr flush dev ipv6leakintrf0
ip addr flush dev lo
ip addr flush dev pvpnksintrf0
ip addr flush dev pvpnroutintrf0
ip addr flush dev wlp0s20f3
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart && sudo dhclient
```

Any clue how to find out what is causing this?

Comment: have you set up Google in your on-line accounts?  `settings > On Line Accounts` If so, try removing it.

Comment: No Google is not set in my On Line Accounts.